# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, min

```
SELECT MIN(retail)
FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER'
```

works fine, but when I include title in select like:

```
SELECT MIN(retail), title
FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER'
```

it doesn't. Why? How to make it work?

Comment: What specifically would you want it to do, in plain English?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL not a single-group group function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795198/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rhys's answer is correct, if that is what you mean, but you might have wanted the `title`(s) where `retail=MIN(retail)`, and that wording suggests how to get that answer:

```
SELECT title, retail
FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER'
 AND retail = (SELECT MIN(retail) FROM books WHERE category = 'COMPUTER')
```

To reduce duplication you can use a `WITH` clause (if you're using a recent version of SQL):

```
;WITH ComputerBooks AS (
  SELECT title, retail
  FROM books
  WHERE category = 'COMPUTER')
SELECT title, retail
FROM ComputerBooks
WHERE retail = (SELECT MIN(retail) FROM ComputerBooks)
```

[Sample I used to confirm syntax.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/98049/simple-test-for-so5591154)

Comment: Why does it require such duplicated constructions?

Comment: It looks like I have to specify condition for each column, and then more general condition (title FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER') is narrowed down to a more specific. But why not have syntax allowing to specify other columns from the record retrieved given a specific condition for one column?

Answer (score 6):

MIN applies to a group of records, so you need to tell it which group of records you mean.

If you mean for each title, show the minimum of retail, then you need:

```
SELECT MIN(retail), title FROM books
WHERE category = 'COMPUTER'
GROUP BY title
```