# SQL Query 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: teacher, & class.
here's the descriptions:

```
TEACHER
 ----------------
 TEACHER_ID
 FIRST_NAME
 LAST_NAME
 TYPE_CODE
 HOME_ROOM_NUM
 PHONE_NUM
 START_DATE
 HOME_STATE
 SCHOOL_ID

 Class
 --------------------
 CLASS_ID
 CLASS_NAME
 TEACHER_ID
 MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE
```

Im trying to figure out how to count the number of classes a given teacher teaches.
here's what I have tried:
1.  How many classes does Lisa Jones teach, if any?

```
SQL> select teacher.last_name, teacher.first_name, class.class_name as 
  2  from teacher, class
  3  where teacher.teacher_id = '2'
  4  AND class.teacher_id = '2';
```

here's the result I get:

```
LAST_NAME         FIRST_NAME        CLASS_ID CLASS_NAME           TEACHER_ID  MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE

----------------- ----------------- -------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------
JONES             LISA               2       Basic CALCULUS       2           10
JONES             LISA               9       Physics 230          2           20
```

I just need teacher name, Id, and # of classes, not having any luck w/ the COUNT function.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest eliminating the deprecated implicit joins and replacing with standard explicit joins:
Just need a `GROUP BY` to get the `COUNT()` to work properly.

```
SELECT t.last_name, t.first_name, t.Teacher_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CLASS_ID) as Classes_Count 
FROM teacher t
JOIN class c
  ON t.Teacher_ID = c.Teacher_ID
WHERE t.Teacher_ID = '2'
GROUP BY t.last_name, t.first_name, t.Teacher_ID
```

You may or may not want `DISTINCT` in the count, depending on the nature of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the @GOAT CO solution is correct. Thi squery is working without JOIN statement:

```
select t.last_name, t.first_name, c.class_name, COUNT(DISTINCT c.CLASS_ID) as Classes_Count from teacher t, class c where t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id and t.teacher_id = 1 GROUP BY t.LAST_NAME, t.FIRST_NAME, t.TEACHER_ID;
```

**EDIT**: Now I add alias for Teacher and Class table and add group statement to script. Can you try it? I tested only on Fiddle.

Here is [SQL FIDDLE link.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45b9f/2/0)

**EDIT2**: Meanwhile I check `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591154/ora-00937-not-a-single-group-group-function) and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795198/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function). But this script don't get this exception. If you modified statement please share it!

Comment: I keep getting an error:
select teacher.last_name, teacher.first_name, class.class_name, COUNT(DISTINCT CLASS_ID) as Classes_Count
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Your query still has a join in it - but it's an outdated, old-style implicit join in the where clause.