# Oracle - not single group func

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table :

```
table blah:  
| name | nmb |
+------+-----+
| andy | 10  |
| alice|  5  |
| carol|  9  |
```

```
select name,MAX(nmb) from blah;
```

Not a single-group group function,
How to get output like :

```
| name | nmb |
+------+-----+
| andy | 10  |
```

Could anyone guide in the right direction?

Comment: @Pang I think it is just a typo  andy=andi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL not a single-group group function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795198/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX( name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY nmb ) AS name,
       MAX( nmb ) AS nmb
FROM   blah
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   blah
  ORDER BY nmb DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the `group by` clause

```
select name, MAX(nmb) from blah group by name;
```

But it will not give you the result you are expecting. In fact it will return the same result as you have on your table.

```
table blah:
| name | nmb |
| andy | 10  |
| alice|  5  |
| carol|  9  |
```

That's because it will group the values by the column `name` since there are no repeated names it will show you all registries.

If you want to get just the name with bigger `nmb` you have to add an where clause and a subquery to get only one registry like this:

```
select name, nmb
  from (select name, MAX(nmb) as nmb
          from blah
         group by name
        order by MAX(nmb) desc) as t
 where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Have you refreshed this page?