# Single group function error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT name 
FROM instructor natural join teaches
WHERE course_id = (SELECT course_id 
                  FROM (SELECT course_id, MAX(mycount) 
                        FROM (SELECT course_id, count(ID) as mycount 
                              FROM takes GROUP BY course_id)));
```

This query doesn't work in oracle. It shows `single group function` error.

Comment: Please better tell what would you like to obtain and post what are your tables. This query is very por quality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL not a single-group group function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795198/sql-not-a-single-group-group-function)

Answer (score 0):

Could be you obtain more then a result try in  and missing a group by

```
SELECT name 
FROM instructor natural join teaches
WHERE course_id IN  (SELECT course_id 
              FROM (SELECT course_id, MAX(mycount) 
                    FROM (SELECT course_id, count(ID) as mycount 
                          FROM takes GROUP BY course_id) 
                    GROUP BY course_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a group by. :)

```
SELECT name FROM instructor 
    natural join teaches 
    WHERE course_id = 
    (SELECT course_id FROM 
        (SELECT course_id, MAX(mycount) FROM 
            (SELECT course_id, count(ID) as mycount FROM takes GROUP BY course_id)
        group by course_ID) -- don't forget this one!
    );
```

Also, that outer subquery won't really do anything.  You've already got one row per course_ID, so the max(mycount) will be exactly the same as mycount.

Answer (score 0):

lThe error occurs in your second level of subqueries:

```
(SELECT course_id, MAX(mycount) 
 FROM (SELECT course_id, count(ID) as mycount 
       FROM takes
       GROUP BY course_id)
)
```

You have an aggregation function but no `GROUP BY`.

I would also advise you to avoid `NATURAL JOIN`.  This is just a bug waiting to happen.  Hiding the keys used for the join is a *bad* thing, that makes queries harder to understand and more prone to error.

And then, your query is rather hard to follow.  I would suggest that you ask another question, providing sample data and desired results.  There is probably a simpler way to express this.